# Add Image component to new gameobject

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, scripting, gameobject

I created a new game object:

```
GameObject newObject = new GameObject("ObjectName");
newObject.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
newObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector2(width, height);
```

I'm looking for a way to add an image (script) for color purposes.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same way you are adding RectTransform.

```
newObject.AddComponent<Image>();
```

You also need to add `using UnityEngine.UI` to be able to find the Image component.

Comment: `using UnityEngine.UI` that is what I missed!

Answer (score 3):

This adds the Image component to your GameObject:

```
newObject.AddComponent<Image>();
```

More things has to be done in order for the `Image` component to show:

**1**.Create a Canvas. The includes creating the GameObject that will hold the Canvas then attach Canvas component to it. You also have to attach other important UI components such as `CanvasScaler` and `GraphicRaycaster` to the `Canvas`.

**2**.Create your `Image` GameObject with your `new GameObject("ObjectName");` then call `newObject.AddComponent<Image>();` to attach Image component to that GameObject.

**3**.Make that `Image` GameObject a child of the `Canvas`.

This is the whole process of creating a Canvas and an Image as the child:

```
void Start()
{
    //Create Canvas
    GameObject canvas = createCanvas(false);

    //Create your Image GameObject
    GameObject newObject = new GameObject("ObjectName");

    //Make the GameObject child of the Canvas
    newObject.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform);

    //Add Image Component to it(This will add RectTransform as-well)
    newObject.AddComponent<Image>();

    //Center Image to screen
    newObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = Vector2.zero;
}



//Creates Hidden GameObject and attaches Canvas component to it
private GameObject createCanvas(bool hide)
{
    //Create Canvas GameObject
    GameObject tempCanvas = new GameObject("Canvas");
    if (hide)
    {
        tempCanvas.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideAndDontSave;
    }

    //Create and Add Canvas Component
    Canvas cnvs = tempCanvas.AddComponent<Canvas>();
    cnvs.renderMode = RenderMode.ScreenSpaceOverlay;
    cnvs.pixelPerfect = false;

    //Set Cavas sorting order to be above other Canvas sorting order
    cnvs.sortingOrder = 12;

    cnvs.targetDisplay = 0;

    addCanvasScaler(tempCanvas);
    addGraphicsRaycaster(tempCanvas);
    return tempCanvas;
}

//Adds CanvasScaler component to the Canvas GameObject 
private void addCanvasScaler(GameObject parentaCanvas)
{
    CanvasScaler cvsl = parentaCanvas.AddComponent<CanvasScaler>();
    cvsl.uiScaleMode = CanvasScaler.ScaleMode.ScaleWithScreenSize;
    cvsl.referenceResolution = new Vector2(800f, 600f);
    cvsl.matchWidthOrHeight = 0.5f;
    cvsl.screenMatchMode = CanvasScaler.ScreenMatchMode.MatchWidthOrHeight;
    cvsl.referencePixelsPerUnit = 100f;
}

//Adds GraphicRaycaster component to the Canvas GameObject 
private void addGraphicsRaycaster(GameObject parentaCanvas)
{
    GraphicRaycaster grcter = parentaCanvas.AddComponent<GraphicRaycaster>();
    grcter.ignoreReversedGraphics = true;
    grcter.blockingObjects = GraphicRaycaster.BlockingObjects.None;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`RectTransform` is mostly used for UI purposes. If you have a canvas already set up, then you can add an `Image` component, but you'll want to set it as a child of your canvas:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ImageTest : MonoBehaviour {
    public Canvas canvas;
    public Sprite sprite;
    public float width = 10;
    public float height = 10;

    private void Start () {
        GameObject newObject = new GameObject("ObjectName");
        RectTransform rectTransform = newObject.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
        rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(width, height);
        Image image = newObject.AddComponent<Image>();
        image.sprite = sprite;
        newObject.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);
    }
};
```

If you just want to put the sprite in the scene, you can use a `SpriteRenderer`:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SpriteTest : MonoBehaviour {
    public Sprite sprite;

    private void Start () {
        GameObject newObject = new GameObject("ObjectName");
        SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer = newObject.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        spriteRenderer.sprite = sprite;
    }
}
```

Or to simply show a texture, you can override the main texture on the material of a `MeshRenderer`:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class TextureTest : MonoBehaviour {
    public Texture texture;

    private void Start () {
        GameObject newObject = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Quad);
        MeshRenderer meshRenderer = newObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        meshRenderer.material.mainTexture = texture;
    }
}
```