# Unity add Text by C# but don't show

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text

My unity version is 5.5.2f. I try to use C# to create a text and add it to a parent GameObject A, but it doesn't show. I have add a texture to the parent GameObject A, and I can see the texture.

When I run the program, I found  Preferred Width and Preferred Height is zero for the text, so I guess it may cause the problem.

Here is my code, Obj is the parent GameObject A.

```
public void setText(string value)
{

    if (text == null)
    {

        GameObject targetObj = new GameObject();

        Canvas canvas = Obj.AddComponent<Canvas>();
        canvas.transform.SetParent(Obj.transform ,false);


        targetObj.name = "displayTextObject";
        targetObj.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);

        text = targetObj.AddComponent<Text>();

        text.name = "displayText";

        Color color = new Color(0, 0, 0);

        text.color = color;

        Font font = new Font("Arial");

        text.font = font;

        gridBgObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    text.text = value;
}
```

Comment: The Text must be under a Canvas. If the text has a parent Object, that parent Object must be under a Canvas.

Comment: @Programmer I have edit the answer, but the text still doesn't show. Do you mean the canvas has to be root object and it should have no parent?

Comment: It seems like you don't even have Canvas in the Scene. You should create one from the Editor  by going to GameObject-->UI-->Canvas. After that, use a public Canvas to hold that Canvas and you can then use it as the parent of your Text. If you decide to create Canvas from script then use the `createCanvas` function from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43844000/3785314) answer. It returns the parent Canvas so you can use the returned GameObject as the parent of the `Text`.

Comment: If that doesn't show then reset the Text position to the middle of the screen. You can do this with `RectTransform.anchoredPosition3D`. Note that `RectTransform` is automatically attached to the `Text` after you make it a child of the `Canvas`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44186367/3785314) for how to change the UI/Text position.

Comment: @Programmer ok,I will try. Thank you.

Comment: Oh geeze, `Canvas canvas = Obj.AddComponent<Canvas>(); canvas.transform.SetParent(Obj.transform ,false);` These two lines tell Unity to make the canvas's GO the parent of itself: you add the canvas to `Obj` and then set the canvas's transform (which *is* Obj's transform because they're attached to the same GO) to `Obj.transform`. I'm pretty sure this has the net effect of setting the parent to null (moving Obj to scene root if it wasn't already).

Answer (score 0):

try with `instanciate`

make a prefab contains

Canvas

- Text
- TextDisplay

or

RectTransform

- Text
- TextDisplay
  (if you choose this you must set parent to canvas)

in
TextDisplay.cs

```
[RequireComponent (typeof (Text))]
public class TextDisplay : MonoBehaviour{
    public Text targetText;

    void Awake(){
        targetText = GetComponent<Text> ();
    }

    public void SetText(string messageToDisplay){
        targetText.text = messageToDisplay;
    }

}
```

in your controller script.

```
public GameObject textDisplayPrefab;
public Transform rootTransform;

public TextDisplay CreateNewTextDisplay(){
    GameObject newTextDisplayObject = Instanciate(textDisplayPrefab) as GameObject;
    newTextDisplayObject.transform.SetParent(rootTransform, false);
    TextDisplay newTextDisplay = newTextDisplayObject.GetComponent<TextDisplay>();
return newTextDisplay;

}
```

and you can do something like this.

```
if(textDisplay == null){
    textDisplay = CreateNewTextDisplay();
    textDisplay.SetText("your string here!!");

}
```